# Craw data from urls by passing URL to Scrapy from other *.py file

Tags: python, scrapy, data-science, web-mining

I'm using Scrapy to craw data from website, and this is my code at file spider.py in folder spider of Scrapy

```py
class ThumbSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    userInput = readInputData('input/user_input.json')
    name = 'thumb'
    # start_urls = ['https://vietnamnews.vn/politics-laws', 'https://vietnamnews.vn/society']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super(ThumbSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.start_urls = kwargs.get('start_urls')

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for cssThumb in self.userInput['cssThumb']: # browse each cssThumb which user provides
            items = response.css('{0}::attr(href)'.format(cssThumb)).getall() # access it

            for item in items:
                item = response.urljoin(item)
                yield scrapy.Request(url=item, callback=self.parse_details)

    def parse_details(self, response):
        data = response.css('div.vnnews-text-post p span::text').extract()

        with open('result/page_content.txt', 'a') as outfile:
            json.dump(data, outfile)

        yield data
```

I call class `ThumbSpider` in file **main.py** and run this file in terminal

```py
import json
import os
import modules.misc as msc
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from week_7.spiders.spider import NaviSpider, ThumbSpider

process2 = CrawlerProcess()

process2.crawl(ThumbSpider, start_urls=['https://vietnamnews.vn/politics-laws', 'https://vietnamnews.vn/society'])
process2.start()
```

My program doesn't get anything from 2 urls, but when I uncomment `start_urls = ['https://vietnamnews.vn/politics-laws', 'https://vietnamnews.vn/society']` and delete `__init__` and `start_requests` methods in class `ThumbSpider` and in file **main.py** edit `process2.crawl(ThumbSpider, start_urls=msc.getUserChoices())` into `process2.crawl(ThumbSpider)` it worked well. I don't know what happening. Anyone can help me, thank you so much

Comment: Does it work if you use a parameter name other than `start_urls` to pass them to the spider?

Comment: it still worked well if this code like this: `process2.crawl(ThumbSpider, start_urls=['https://vietnamnews.vn/politics-laws', 'https://vietnamnews.vn/society'])`, but when I changed it into `process2.crawl(ThumbSpider, start_urls=msc.getUserChoices())` it will not work, the getUserChoices() gets data from json file and return a list of urls

Comment: Does `msc.getUserChoices()` return `['https://vietnamnews.vn/politics-laws', 'https://vietnamnews.vn/society']`, or something else?

Comment: yes `msc.getUserChoices()` return `['https://vietnamnews.vn/politics-laws', 'https://vietnamnews.vn/society']`

Comment: `['https://vietnamnews.vn/politics-laws', 'https://vietnamnews.vn/society']` is contained in a json file

Comment: It does not make sense to me that `['a', 'b']` works but a call that returns `['a', 'b']` does not. I can only assume that function is not returning `['a', 'b']`, with the information given.

Comment: I am sure that the `getUserChoices()` function returning a list of urls because I tested it, but I don't know why it does not work when I assign it to start_urls